# SAS: Case When then execute query

Tags: sql, sas

I want to execute a query only when a condition is satisfied.
The code I want to execute is:

```
proc sql NOPRINT OUTOBS=1;
%CASE WHEN (&_count_ > 0) THEN
DELETE FROM TABLE T
WHERE T.Period = xxxxxx
END;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `IF` instead of `CASE`:

```
proc sql NOPRINT OUTOBS=1;
%IF(&_count_ > 0) %THEN %DO
DELETE FROM TABLE T
WHERE T.Period = xxxxxx
%END;
quit;
```

Comment: same error: ERROR: The %IF statement is not valid in open code.

Comment: @mkharraz You need to define a macro containing the code above and then call the macro in order to use the `%if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

i found the solution:

```
%macro delete_rows();
PROC SQL;
DELETE FROM Table T
WHERE Period=xxxxxx;
QUIT;
%mend;

%macro check_if();
%IF (&nbr_rows > 0) %THEN 
    %delete_rows();
%mend;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
proc sql;
DELETE FROM T
WHERE &_count_ > 0 and Period = xxxxxx
;quit;
```

Comment: This doesn't conditionally execute the query, it conditionally evaluates the where clause, row by row.

Comment: That's right - it's all that this scenario requires.

The only reason for executing a conditional query in this case might be performance. SAS will probably read every row even if the where condition is obviously false. If the table `T` is stored in a more sophisticated database no records will be read if `&_count_ > 0` is false though.